# Remove an underscore with Regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Like the title says, i would like to remove an underscore within a String with a regex. This is what i have:

```
  function palindrome(str) {

     str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '',/\s/g, '',/[0-9]/g,'');  
        if (str.split("").reverse().join("") !== str) {
           return false;
        }
        else {
           return true;
        }
   }
palindrome("eye");
```

Comment: This should work. What is not working? _Note:_ You don't need `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: yes, but it seems that the underscores aren't removed.

Comment: You need to assign the result `str = str.replace...` to the variable.

Comment: @Tushar i did this in my code

Comment: `.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '',/\s/g, '',/[0-9]/g,'')` you can't use `replace` like this. You can chain them `.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[0-9]/g,'')`. In your case you don't need this, you can use `str.replace(/_/g, '');`

Comment: **Code:** `str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/_/g, ''); return str === str.split('').reverse().join('');` Only keep this code in the `palindrome` function.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `.replace(/_/g, "")` to remove all underscores or use `.replace(/_/g, " ")` to replace them with a space.

Here is an example to remove them:

```js
var str = "Yeah_so_many_underscores here";
var newStr = str.replace(/_/g, "");
alert(newStr);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
str.replace(/_/g, '');
```

This should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.replace` to achieve this. Use the following code. It will replace all `_` with the `second parameter`. In our case we don't need a second parameter so all `_` will be removed.

```
<script>
var str = "some_sample_text_here.";
var newStr = str.replace(/_/g , "");
alert ('Text without underscores : ' + newStr);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove **underscore** from response or any string
**like this: "hello_rizo"**

**Code:**

```
var rizo="hello_rizo"
console.log('output', e.response.data.message.replace(/(^|_)./g, s => s.slice(-1).toUpperCase()));
```

**output:**
hellorizo